# Is that possible search stock item by attribute

Tags: rest, acumatica

My stock item has different checkbox attributes.
`Attribute1`,  `Attribute2`, `Attribute3`
I want to get all stock items with `Attribute=true`.
I have tried `Attributes[Attribute1] eq false` but it doesn't work.

By doesn't work it means:

> 0.0.0.0/test1/entity/default/6.00.001/$pxpand=Attributes&filter=Attribute[Attribute1]
>   eq true

It does not return the correct result.

Comment: can you show us what you tried to do, and defined `it doesn't work`

Comment: Sorry doesn't work meaning:
http://0.0.0.0/test1/entity/default/6.00.001/stockitem?$expand=Attributes&filter=Attributes[Attribute1] eq true 
it does not return the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are not part of the item's DAC, the attribute system is handled uniquely by the database since the whole system is user created and editable.  Attributes as they are created by the user, are stored in the table CSAttribute and tables named similarly.  Actual Attribute data is held in CSAnswers table which is a table of created attribute data.  You need to create a query of the CSAnswer table using your attributeid and the noteid of you parent table.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The CSAnswers table stores all values as strings, even when they behave like boolean types in the UI. All of the attribute values for every single attribute in the system are stored in the same database column, CSAnswers.Value - to access a value, the keys of this table are the NoteID of the DAC, and the AttributeID of the attribute. This means that all of the values must be the same type - they're all strings.

So even though the attribute you're targeting is configured as a "Checkbox" type, the actual value stored in the database is a string with either `'0'` or `'1'` values. The API call you've composed is treating the attribute value as a boolean type. Try using the string value `'1'` in place of the boolean value `true` in your filter.